# Trying to find 2nd last order date for the customer

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to find maximum orderdate(means most recent) and the second last orderdate(means second last purchase)

output looks like this

```
> Emailaddress   MostRecentPurchase 2ndMostRecentPurchase   totalorder
> xyz@gmail.com  1/29/2018             1/11/2018              $30

SELECT
Customers.EmailAddress,
'$'+CAST(SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) AS VARCHAR(12)) as TotalOrdered
FROM Customers,Orders
WHERE Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2017 00:00' AND '12/31/2017 23:59'
AND Orders.OrderDate = ( SELECT MAX(Orders.OrderDate) 
               FROM Orders
               WHERE OrderDate < ( SELECT MAX(OrderDate) 
                              FROM Orders
                            )
             ) 
GROUP BY Customers.EmailAddress
ORDER BY TotalOrdered DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  How about this?

```
select c.customerid, min(o.orderdate), max(o.orderdate), sum(o.paymentamount)
from customers c cross apply
     (select top (2) o.*
      from orders o
      where o.customerid = c.customerid
      order by o.orderdate desc
     ) o
group by c.customerid;
```

You can also do this using `row_number()`, but I'm into practicing lateral joins today.

Note:  This leaves out the date comparisons (because the text description does not mention them) and the final formatting for the amount.

EDIT:

The equivalent query with `row_number()` is probably a tad less efficient:

```
select c.customerid, min(o.orderdate), max(o.orderdate), sum(o.paymentamount)
from customers c join
     (select o.*, row_number() over (partition by o.customerid order by o.oderdate desc) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
     on o.customerid = c.customerid and o.seqnum <= 2
group by c.customerid;
```

Y

Comment: ..Giving me incorrect syntax error near apply..and all the customers are unique by emailaddress and not by customerid. I forgot to mention

Comment: @c_174 . . . That should be `cross apply`.

Comment: ..The syntax error is gone by using cross apply but in the output result i am getting only customerid..and nothing else where as i needed the other columns too..any help please

Comment: ..Its is still showing me customerid column only in final results and not the other three..Though this is weired but i am not getting why this happening..tried with apply and row number both

Comment: @c_174 . . . Both queries should be returning four columns.

Comment: @ Gordon LinoffI tried both of your ways and very strange is it is still returning me only one column that is customerid.

Comment: @c_174 . . . That is very strange.